# ffmpeg error while segmenting

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm using ffmpeg and segmenter on Ubuntu 10.04 to create the transport stream from flv/h264 video files and then segment the ts segments for ipad streaming.

Some ts files show an error with segmenter -

> Output #0, mpegts, to '29':
>       Stream #0.0: Video: 0x0000, yuv420p, 480x360, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 25
>   tbc
>       Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x0000, 0 channels, s16 
>   **[mpegts @> 0x11f4ac0]sample rate not set** 
>   **Could not write mpegts header to first
>   output file**

my ffmpeg command for creating the ts file -

> ffmpeg -i 1.flv -f mpegts -acodec
>   libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 480x360
>   -vcodec libx264 -b 192k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40
>   -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 192k -bufsize 192k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin
>   10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect
>   480:360 -g 30 -async 2 -y 1.ts

my segmenter command -

> segmenter 1.ts 10 1 1.m3u8
>   path/to/streams/

Answer (score 0):

I have switched from libfaac to libmp3lame for audio encoding and this workaround is working so far. Not sure what went wrong with libfaac encoding.